# API Equivalent for Sabre host command WPNCS

Tags: sabre

Could you please help me to find API Equivalent for Sabre host command **WPNCS** (Search for lowest fare even if not
available)

but can't find correct request in API docs

Please Help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check OTA_AirPriceLLSRQ

https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_apis/air/book/price_air_itinerary

The request design document shows a reference to WPNCS:
http://webservices.sabre.com/drc/servicedoc/OTA_AirPriceLLSRQ_v2.12.0_Design.xml

Note that you can do the same from the orchestrated booking service (EnhancedAirBook):
http://files.developer.sabre.com/doc/providerdoc/ServicesPlatform/EnhancedAirBookRQ_v3.6.0_Design.xml